# Selecting distinct datetimes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently learning how to use Ruby on Rails with [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.org) and right now I'm tackling making forms. I'm trying to pull unique dates from my database to populate a dropdown options box for a project. I'm using `form_for` in my view and I am using the `select` function which takes an array of arrays i.e. [["option one", 1], ["option two", 2]] etc. The idea is that only unique dates that are in the database should show up in the options. My problem is duplicate dates keep showing up e.g.

```
03/03/2016
03/03/2016
04/03/2016
05/03/2016
06/03/2016
06/03/2016
```

Using find_by_sql I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT start FROM flights
```

to no avail. After a quick Google search I tried

```
SELECT start FROM flights GROUP BY start
```

but I'm still getting duplicates. I'm not the best with SQL so any help would be appreciated.

edit:

My datatime column does have a time component so that's probably the issue

From the db schema here is my flights table if it's any help

```
create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "from_airport_id"
  t.integer  "to_airport_id"
  t.datetime "start"
  t.integer  "flight_duration"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end
```

Comment: (1) What is the datatype of `start`?  (2) What database are you using?  The most likely problem is that `start` has a time component, and you need to just extract the date (or format the result so you see the time component).

Comment: You mean `SELECT DISTINCT` returns duplicate rows? Very odd. Is that the whole select?!?

Comment: @gordonlinoff In Rails it just says datetime, but it does include a time component. That's probably the issue, I'll try formatting just to get the time portion although I'm not sure how to do it. I'll check google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching online I found a much easier way to get the result I wanted. Using the `:pluck` method as a short cut to pull just the attributes I wanted from the database, calling `:to_date` on the datetime to remove the time component, then calling `:uniq` to just get the unique dates like I required.

```
Flight.pluck(:start).map {|a| [a.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), a.to_date]}.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

If selecting distinct dates is still getting duplicates, it is most likely that the date format has time, and the dates have different times.

You should cast the column start to date `CAST(start AS DATE)` to convert the column to date, and only then use the group by.

Comment: No need for any `GROUP BY` here, `SELECT DISTINCT` will do just fine.

Comment: Yes @jarlh! I completely forgot that detail.

Comment: I tried using `SELECT CAST(start AS DATE) FROM flights GROUP BY start` but it just returned a lot of Flight objects with `nil` for the ID attribute but no start/datetime attribute. @jarlh If I use distinct it just returns one flight object.

Comment: @SkipCloud, show us the complete `SELECT DISTINCT` query.

Comment: @jarlh `Flight.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT CAST(start AS DATE) FROM flights")`

Using rails console it returns `Flight Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT CAST(start AS DATE) FROM flights
 => [#<Flight id: nil>] `

Comment: @SkipCloud, I'm sorry, but I don't know ruby on rails, so I can't understand why you expect a flight id to be returned when you only select a date. (A date that may correspond to several flights.)

Comment: @jarlh When you call find_by_sql method on the Flight model ActiveRecord fetches the requested columns from the database database and returns them as Flight objects so you can do other things with the information. That would explain why there is an id attribute I guess.